# Subtraction with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, subtraction

I am developing a joomla extension and in default.php file i have this code:

```
foreach($this->subv as $subv) {
    $giorni = ((int)$subv->data_fine - (int)$subv->data_inizio);
    $ore = ($giorni * 24) % 24;
    echo $giorni.' : '.$ore;
}
```

$this->subv is an object that contains the result of a mysql query. My problem is that echo prints $subv->data_fine value, and not the result of the substraction. $subv->data_fine and $subv->data_inizio contain the result of time() function.
How can i resolve it this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: What is format of $subv->data_fine, please give me var_dump($subv->data_fine) result.

Comment: And by the way, won't `$ore` always be `0`?

Comment: the result of var_dump is string(10) "1318926057"

Comment: $ore is always 0, yes, but it doesn't matter now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you problem correctly, `$giorni` is equal to `$subv->data_fine`, which would simply mean that `(int)$subv->data_inizio` evaluates to zero. Have you checked that?

Comment: $subv->data_fine and $subv->data_inizio contain the result of time() function (called in different tme..)

Comment: If you subtract y from x and the result is equal to x, there's no possibility other than y being zero. You've given the var_dump() for data_fine, now give the one for data_inizio. So far, my crystal ball tells me it's null, which will evaluate to zero when cast to int :) Just var_dump($subv) and you'll see what's wrong..

Comment: Yes, you're right, is NNULL. Now the problem is: why is it NULL?

Comment: We cannot guess by the code you've provided so far. Show some more code if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @pindol: why use php when mysql can do it for you? (check my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql to get the difference between 2 dates (DATEDIFF function):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff